# How to iterate through a container within a const container?

Tags: c++, loops, constants

Suppose you have the incomplete function iterate that has the following parameter, a `const` map that has `pair<int, vector<string>>` and the following loops:

```
string iterate(const map<int, vector<string>>& m) {
    for (map<int, vector<string>>::const_iterator start_iter = m.begin(); start_iter != m.end(); ++start_iter) {   
        for (auto vector_iter = m[(*start_iter).first].begin(); vector_iter != m[(*start_iter).first].end(); ++vector_iter) {
        }
    }
}
```

Iterating through a const map requires that the iterator be const, `map<int, vector<string>>::const_iterator`.  That makes sense. However, when trying to iterate through the vector within the `const`map what type does `auto` have to be, or is it not possible to iterate through a container within a const container. I tried making `auto` `vector<string>::const_iterator`, but the function still fails. Am I missing something?

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: @immibis No viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const map<int, vector<string> >' (aka 'const map<int, vector<basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > > >')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really, do yourself a favor and use range based for loops:

```
for (auto&& [key, vec] : m) {
    for (auto&& vec_element : vec) {
        // All vec elements
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use C++17 (you should, C++17 is great!) then do that:

```
for (auto&& m_element : m) {
    for (auto&& vec_element : m_element.second) {
        // All vec elements
    }
}
```

---

If you *really* want to use use iterators (you really should use range based for loops) then continue reading.

You are not using iterator correctly. You are using a iterator that points on an element in the map, then get it's key to get back the element. This is not how to use an iterator.

Instead, you should use the object the iterator is pointing to *directly*.

```
for (auto start_iter = m.begin(); start_iter != m.end(); ++start_iter) {   
    for (auto vector_iter = start_iter->second.begin(); vector_iter != start_iter->second.end(); ++vector_iter) {
        // shuff with vector_iter
    }
}
```

---

Now why does `operator[]` failed?

That's because it's a `std::map`. A with a map, you should be able to create something on the fly:

```
// creates element at key `123`
m[123] = {"many", "strings", "in", "vector"};
```

For the element to be created by the container at a new key, it must save that new element in itself, so it must mutate itself to provide `operator[]`, so it's not const.

You could have also use `std::map::at()`, but it isn't worth it in your case. Using either `operator[]` or `map.at(key)` will make the map search for the key, which isn't trivial in complexity.

Comment: @Art yes,  the elements of a const map are const too.

Comment: is the vector within the const map considered const?